# jquery's html() method not effectively inserting html code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get javascript to render an embedded google map once the user's coordinates are obtained.

The code that gets the lat & long works, so I wont show it, but here's the gist of it

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    //previous code calculating lat & lng, etc
    showMap(lat, lng);
  function showMap(lat,lng) {
    var apikey = "asdfasdfasdfasdf";
    var code = "<iframe width='480' height='320' frameborder='0' style='border:0' src='https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/view?zoom=14&center=" + lat + "," + lng + "&key=" + apikey + "></iframe>";
    console.log(code) //outputs good code
    $("#map").html(code)
  }
 }
</script>
```

Note that this does work....

```
$("#map").html("<h2>FML</h2>");
```

That works.

Comment: you are missing some brackets and semicolons. at the end of `$(document).ready(.......)` that closing bracket is missing. after console log `;` missing

Comment: ); missing at the end of $(document).ready(function(){.....}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Missing the closing `'` for the src attribute.

```
..."&key=" + apikey + "></iframe>";
```

needs to be

```
..."&key=" + apikey + "'></iframe>";
                    ^
```

Answer (score 2):

test if it is working with all the typo's corrected:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    //previous code calculating lat & lng, etc
    var lat = 1234;
    var lng = 5678;
    showMap(lat, lng);
  });
  function showMap(lat,lng) {
    var apikey = "asdfasdfasdfasdf";
    var code = "<iframe width='480' height='320' frameborder='0' style='border:0' src='https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/view?zoom=14&center=" + lat + "," + lng + "&key=" + apikey + "'></iframe>";
    console.log(code); //outputs good code
    $("#map").html(code);
  }
</script>
```

(credit to @epascarello for the missing "'")